# Match between two dataframes and add result to the column of one of them (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, match

I have the following dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'results': ['hi how why', 'which how raw', 'final what is']})

df_v2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'results': ['John', 'Peter', 'Anne']})
```

What I have to do is to look for if the user is the same between the two dataframes, if it is the same I have to add the results column in the second dataframe in the first one, to look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'results': ['hi how why John', 'which how raw Peter', 'final what is Anne']})
```

Any ideas of how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set_index` method to tell `pandas` how to align dataframes when performing operations like addition, subtraction, etc.

```
new_series = df.set_index("user")["results"] + " " + df_v2.set_index("user")["results"]

print(new_series)
user
A        hi how why John
B    which how raw Peter
C     final what is Anne
Name: results, dtype: object
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `merge` function to combine your dataframes (which will also perform the aligning operation for you), and then add the columns on the `merge`'d dataframe:

```
new_df = df.merge(df_v2, on="user").assign(newcol=lambda d: d["results_x"] + " " + d["results_y"])

print(new_df)
  user      results_x results_y               newcol
0    A     hi how why      John      hi how why John
1    B  which how raw     Peter  which how raw Peter
2    C  final what is      Anne   final what is Anne
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as follows if user in each frame is unique. and nor repeated;

```
df['results']=df['results']+ ' '+df_v2['results']
```

For accuracy, merge and concat

```
df_new=pd.merge(df,df_v2, how='left', on='user' )
df_new=df_new.assign(results=df_new['results_x']+ ' '+df_new['results_y']).drop(columns=['results_x','results_y'])
df_new
```